# Puppeteer sometimes works sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have the following code

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
    const plenty = await getDefiDappData('https://dappradar.com/tezos/defi/plenty',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]'
    );

    const youves = await getDefiDappData('https://dappradar.com/tezos/defi/youves',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]',
    '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/section/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]'
    );

    return {
        props: {
            plenty,
            youves
        },
        revalidate: 300,
      };
}

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getDefiDappData(url:String, tvlTag:String, tvlChangeTag:String, atvlTag:String, atvlChangeTag:String) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
   
   const [el] = await page.$x(tvlTag);
   const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
   const tvl = await txt.jsonValue();

   const [el2] = await page.$x(tvlChangeTag);
   const txt2 = await el2.getProperty('textContent');
   const tvlChange = await txt2.jsonValue();

   const [el3] = await page.$x(atvlTag);
   const txt3 = await el3.getProperty('textContent');
   const atvl = await txt3.jsonValue();

   const [el4] = await page.$x(atvlChangeTag);
   const txt4 = await el4.getProperty('textContent');
   const atvlChange = await txt4.jsonValue();
   
    browser.close()
    return {tvl, tvlChange, atvl, atvlChange};
}
```

Sometimes it works fine and I get all the data I am looking for, but sometimes one might fail to get anything

Following is the console error:

```
index.js?46cb:352 
        
       Uncaught     at getDefiDappData (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/dex.tsx:187:26)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async getStaticProps (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/dex.tsx:166:20)
    at async Object.renderToHTML (file://C:\Users\a\Documents\Tezos\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:465:20)
    at async doRender (file://C:\Users\a\Documents\Tezos\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:879:38)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.isManualRevalidate.isManualRevalidate (file://C:\Users\a\Documents\Tezos\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:979:28)
    at async (file://C:\Users\a\Documents\TezosNFTs\node_modules\next\dist\server\response-cache.js:64:36)
```

Following is the server error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProperty')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
src\pages\dex.tsx (117:24) @ getDefiDappData

 115 |    
 116 |    const [el] = await page.$x(tvlTag);
> 117 |    const txt = await el.getProperty('textContent');
```

I understand what the error is saying but I don't seem to get why sometimes it works while sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: How about `page.waitForXPath` instead of `page.$x`? `page.$x` assumes the element is ready which may not be the case for your site. As an aside, I'm not a big fan of overly-rigid browser-generated xpaths like you're using. These hyper-specific selectors seem brittle and liable to break if even a little bit of the site DOM structure changes, which happens dynamically all the time. This might be another possible cause for your error.

Comment: replacing it like for like gives me this error "TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable"

Comment: @ggorlen what would be an alternative way to go about getting this data considering DOM structures might change in future?

Comment: It depends on the site, but most items can be selected with classes or ids much more cleanly than "take the third div child of the fourth div child of the second div child of the....". Most selectors would be like `#root .some-class` but I don't know what your page is so I can't answer the question, only point out likely causes. Your TypeError is because `waitForXPath` doesn't return an iterable, just a single element: `const el = await page.waitForXPath(...)`, so you don't need `[]` around `el`.

Comment: it is really a site-dependent issue. maybe they are A/B testing the site and an element has multiple different selectors with each visit. ggorlen is right about using selectors instead of XPath. like that, you could put the selector for the A and B version of the page (if you can spot that that is the problem) making use of the comma CSS separator `'.class-A-version, .class-B-version'` etc.